# Stack Widget Error when using SingleChildScrollView

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this code as profile screen which I need it to be able to fill a text like "HELLO" on this code example. But when I put a lot of text in it, the screen become overflow. 
The problem is everytime I put **SingleChildScrollView** to avoid the overflow, I got another error instead.
Please tell me how I can fix this problem.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: FutureBuilder<Profile>(
            future: dataService.getHttp(),
            builder: ...
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildView(detail) {
    return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.network( 
                    'https://i.imgur.com/2F3Al82.jpg', 
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('HELLO'),
                    ]
                  ),
                )
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 150.0,
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: NetworkImage('https://i.imgur.com/2F3Al82.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
    );
  }
```

this is the error

[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the `Expanded` widget. `SingleChildScrollView` allows for infinite height and expanded will take up as much space as it can these two thing are incompatible if you remove the `Expanded` widget it should work. If you want some space around that container I suggest the `Containers` margin property.